# A Simple Hypothesis on Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Ok guys, I was just tinkering around with primes and found that:

> $P = ((A\cdot2^n)+1)$

where *P* is a prime, *n* is a nonzero positive integer, and *A* is either a prime or a composite number. What i found is that this formula is feasible to find primes as long as you have the correct combination of primes to form composites for *A*, and suitable *n*.

Now, what's interesting is, with *P* increasingly bigger, i've found that:

> Using the formula above, If: $A_1$ denotes a single prime, $A_2$ is a composite formed by two primes, $A_3$ is a composite formed by three primes, etc. Then if $A_k$ is a composite formed by $k$ primes, the number of $P$ with small $k$, **would be bigger**  than the number of $P$ with big $k$ along the number line. (be aware that "big $k$" could mean a prime that is multiplied many times/big power of a prime)

In simple terms, If *A* is just a single prime, with *A* and *n* varied, then the *P* from that would be more numerous than the *P* that is formed from a composite *A* (and the more primes/more power of the same prime used to form *A*, the less that *P* would appear). My question is, is this behavior of primes actually hold true? and can anyone prove it?

for example, using the formula, from 2 to 97 (i've tried by hand) there are:

> $P(A_1)$ (Prime from a single prime): $2,3,5,7,11,17,23,29,47,53,59,67,83,89,97, $(15 primes)
>   $P(A_2)$ (Prime from multiplication of two primes): $13,19,31,41,43,61,71,73,79$ (9 primes)
>   $P(A_3)$ (prime from multiplication of three primes): $37$ (1 prime, with $A_1 = 2\cdot3\cdot3$, and *n* = $1$)

constructive criticisms and corrections are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if $P$ is just a random odd integre, then as $P$ gets large, so will $A$, and so will the probability the $A$ as more and more prime factors ... Or, if you only test up to $P<100$, you certainly cannot find a case of $A_{26}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for your reply. With $A_26$, i was doing it by hand so i really don't know.  But i found that (with the limit of 97), there are actually more P with small prime factors than larger ones (with large primes like 97, there is only one prime factor (3), *but*, the *$2^n$* is large (32)), so an alternative explanation can be made that while P is getting larger, there are more small A's  with bigger $2^n$, than ones with bigger prime factors (and small $2^n$ ). but  *if* that is true, i don't know why.